# Blender's entire interface missing?

Tags: texturing, interface

I've gotten into blender again and was still using 2.79. I downloaded 2.82 on my mac pro today and was met with this screen. I re-downloaded it as well as restarted my computer but nothing works. I downloaded the same file on my laptop and it ran fine. I will appreciate all help and thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: It appears that your OS, graphics driver or hardware doesn't fulfill the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.8x.